# how to know whether or not a image has been loaded using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, events, onload

I'm coding a website that displays picture albums, the page is loading the thumbs and applies white overlays on each picture before they are fully loaded.

I coded this in local and it works fine.
But uploading the files on my server and loading the page brings few errors of display, some white overlay are not fading out because the jQuery *load* function is not triggered since images load before the script is loaded and being applied.

The solution would be to apply white overlay only on images that are still loaded when the jQuery script is being executed.

My question is how to know if a specific element in the page is still being fetched or has completely been rendered on the screen ?

**NOTE :** here's the page http://www.benjamindegenne.com/portfolio/numeric/upper-playground/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded - images loaded jQuery plug in will do that for you ;-)

Answer (score 4):

### Updates

The previous solution was incorrect. (Thanks to @donut).

Here is alternative simple way to do this using jQuery -

```
$(function() {
    $("<img src='img_01.jpg' />").load(function() {
        // Image img_01.jpg has been loaded
    });
});
```

---

<strike>**JavaScript**</strike>

Use Image pre-loading in JavaScript -

```
img1 = new Image();
img1.src = "image.jpg";
// at this line image.jpg has been loaded
```

After `img1.src = "image.jpg";`, you can assure that image has been loaded and you can write your business logic

**jQuery**

Here is a simple jQuery plugin to accomplish this -

```
// image preloading plugin
$.fn.preload = function () {
    this.each(function () {
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        // at this line "this" image has been loaded
    });
};
```

Sample usage -

```
var imagesToPreload = ["img01.jpg", "img02.jpg", "img03.jpg"];
imagesToPreload .preload();
// at this line all images has been loaded
```

Comment: how can I know if the image has been loaded ?

Comment: @Oddantfr U updated the code and added some comments at location where you are assure that images has been loaded

Comment: thanks, this looks great. however it's not appropriate in my case. Have a look to the page if you have time to help. this would be thoughtful. http://www.benjamindegenne.com/portfolio/numeric/upper-playground/

Comment: @Oddantfr I think this can work in your case. Image preloading means they are loaded in the browsers cache. After the image has been loaded, you can change the picture from progress bar to actual image. This time there wont' be any delay because image was already loaded in browsers cache. Let me know in this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Ok I'll try this, I get the idea. I'll make you informed. thanks

Comment: I've placed the script in the header instead at the bottom of pages and without altering any script it works fine. I understand the purpose of your script but since images are not cached (cause the src attribute is calling a php script that create and returns the appropriate thumb) my actual script doesn't need modifications. anyways I'll be taking in consideration the above if someday I change the code. thanks!

Comment: -1 Because this is wrong. The images are not necessarily loaded at the points marked with comments like `// [...] has been loaded`. Setting the `src` attribute of an `<img>` is [non-blocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_synchronization). I've tested this out in [this JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/donut2d/QbDus/).

Comment: @donut thanks for reporting the issue. Yes you are right. I just realized this. Corrected my solution.

Comment: @RameshSoni Another thing to note is that the `src` attribute should be set after binding an action to the `load` event. Otherwise, cached images may not trigger the `load` event. Ran into this issue yesterday with Internet Explorer 7 and 8. And you may want to bind an action to the `error` event as well in case something goes wrong in loading the image.