# How to know when an image load completes

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: Know when an image is fully loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257385/javascript-know-when-an-image-is-fully-loaded)

I have this code:

```
$("#imageOnPage").attr("src", urlString);
```

I need to somehow fire an event after the image becomes visible on the screen.
In other words I need an onLoad event for the image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Know when an image is fully loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257385/javascript-know-when-an-image-is-fully-loaded) and [Check if an image is loaded (no errors) in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript) --- please use the search before you ask a new question, [this has been asked before many times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+test+if+image+loaded).

Comment: Some more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263359/how-can-i-determine-if-an-image-has-loaded-using-javascript-jquery, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712002/how-to-know-whether-or-not-a-image-has-been-loaded-using-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually an event for that:

```
$('#imageOnPage').load(function()
{
/* your code */
});
```

It gets fired when your image has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to bind to the `load` event of the image.

```
$('#imageOnPage').load(function() {
    alert('image loaded');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#imageOnPage').load(function(){
  $(this).attr('src', urlString);
});
```